# language errors in bibliografy (from .bib file)

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, input-encodings

[image]I created a bib file for my references. All my references are in english language. My document is in greek-english language. When I add those references at the end of my document all references are there but in greek text . So I changed the language to english before adding the bibliography and the bibliography is now ok but it creates errors such as: ...unavailiable encoding in encoding T1... and at the same time bibliography entry disappeared from table of contents. How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames]{article} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[verbose, colorlinks=true, naturalnames=true, linkcolor=blue, 
unicode, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek}

\mytitle

 abstract here
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

 a lot of text here with cites

 \newpage

 \cleardoublepage
 \phantomsection
 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Βιβλιογραφία}

 \selectlanguage{english}

 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
 \bibliography{bibfile}

\end{document}
```

bibfile:

```
@article{alsup2006state,
title={The state of English education and a vision for its future: A call to arms},
author={Alsup, Janet and Emig, Janet and Pradl, Gordon and Tremmel, Robert and Yagelski, Robert P and Alvine, Lynn and DeBlase, Gina and Moore, Michael and Petrone, Robert and Sawyer, Mary},
journal={English Education},
volume={38},
number={4},
pages={278--294},
year={2006},
publisher={JSTOR}}

@incollection{wilkinson2016brief,
title={A brief history of serious games},
author={Wilkinson, Phil},
booktitle={Entertainment computing and serious games},
pages={17--41},
year={2016},
publisher={Springer}}

@article{kirriemuir2004literature,
title={Literature review in games and learning},
author={Kirriemuir, John and McFarlane, Angela},
year={2004}}

@article{wu2012investigating,
title={Investigating the learning-theory foundations of game-based learning: 
a meta-analysis},
author={Wu, W-H and Hsiao, H-C and Wu, P-L and Lin, C-H and Huang, S-H},
journal={Journal of Computer Assisted Learning},
volume={28},
number={3},
pages={265--279},
year={2012},
publisher={Wiley Online Library}}

@misc{immunlab,
author = {Joseph Perpich, M.D., Ph.D., Jill Conley, Ph.D.},
title = {{The Virtual Immunology Lab}},
howpublished = 
"\url{http://media.hhmi.org/biointeractive/vlabs/immunology/index.html}",
year = {2018}, 
note = "[Online; accessed 28-March-2018]"}

@misc{caridolab,
author = {Joseph Perpich, M.D., Ph.D., Dennis Liu, Ph.D},
title = {{Cardiology Virtual Lab}},
howpublished = "\url{http://www.hhmi.org/biointeractive/cardiology-virtual-lab}",
year = {2018}, 
note = "[Online; accessed 28-March-2018]"}

@misc{caridolab2,
author = {Joseph Perpich, M.D., Ph.D., Dennis Liu, Ph.D},
title = {{Cardiology Virtual Lab}},
howpublished = "\url{http://www.bio-alive.com/laboratories/cardiology-lab.htm}",
year = {2018}, 
note = "[Online; accessed 28-March-2018]"}
```

Comment: Can you also show a short example of a .bib file? I tried your example and after removing `\mytitle` and adding a bib file of my own, it works fine: greek letters in the body of the file and Latin letters in the references. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy2Rj.png

Comment: I add a picture with a few references from my bibfile.

Comment: Can you please add them as text? I'd like to test if I can reproduce your problem.

Comment: yes I add it. you can check it

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I could find in your code was unrelated to the bibliography, but that `\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Βιβλιογραφία}` only worked every other compilation - not sure why.

As a workaround I suggest the `tocbibind` package instead:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,usenames,dvipsnames]{article} 
\usepackage{ucs} 
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[verbose, colorlinks=true, naturalnames=true, linkcolor=blue, 
unicode, bookmarks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\refname}{\foreignlanguage{greek}{Βιβλιογραφία}}}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{alsup2006state,
title={The state of English education and a vision for its future: A call to arms},
author={Alsup, Janet and Emig, Janet and Pradl, Gordon and Tremmel, Robert and Yagelski, Robert P and Alvine, Lynn and DeBlase, Gina and Moore, Michael and Petrone, Robert and Sawyer, Mary},
journal={English Education},
volume={38},
number={4},
pages={278--294},
year={2006},
publisher={JSTOR}}

@incollection{wilkinson2016brief,
title={A brief history of serious games},
author={Wilkinson, Phil},
booktitle={Entertainment computing and serious games},
pages={17--41},
year={2016},
publisher={Springer}}

@article{kirriemuir2004literature,
title={Literature review in games and learning},
author={Kirriemuir, John and McFarlane, Angela},
year={2004}}

@article{wu2012investigating,
title={Investigating the learning-theory foundations of game-based learning: 
a meta-analysis},
author={Wu, W-H and Hsiao, H-C and Wu, P-L and Lin, C-H and Huang, S-H},
journal={Journal of Computer Assisted Learning},
volume={28},
number={3},
pages={265--279},
year={2012},
publisher={Wiley Online Library}}

@misc{immunlab,
author = {Joseph Perpich, M.D., Ph.D., Jill Conley, Ph.D.},
title = {{The Virtual Immunology Lab}},
howpublished = 
"\url{http://media.hhmi.org/biointeractive/vlabs/immunology/index.html}",
year = {2018}, 
note = "[Online; accessed 28-March-2018]"}

@misc{caridolab,
author = {Joseph Perpich, M.D., Ph.D., Dennis Liu, Ph.D},
title = {{Cardiology Virtual Lab}},
howpublished = "\url{http://www.hhmi.org/biointeractive/cardiology-virtual-lab}",
year = {2018}, 
note = "[Online; accessed 28-March-2018]"}

@misc{caridolab2,
author = {Joseph Perpich, M.D., Ph.D., Dennis Liu, Ph.D},
title = {{Cardiology Virtual Lab}},
howpublished = "\url{http://www.bio-alive.com/laboratories/cardiology-lab.htm}",
year = {2018}, 
note = "[Online; accessed 28-March-2018]"}
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{greek}


 abstract here
\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

 a lot of text here with cites \nocite{*}

 \newpage

 \cleardoublepage
% \phantomsection
% \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Βιβλιογραφία}

 \selectlanguage{english}

 \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
 \bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: that works perfect! thank you! do you know how can I make "references" in greek language in table of contents and in document?

Comment: @orion13 Please see my edited answer

Comment: Perfect! but I have another problem, after compiling a few times all references disappeared from the end of the document (and no errors)

Comment: @orion13 Can you try to boil your new problem down to a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407)?

Comment: if I understood correctly, I believe that its the same as your solution.

Comment: @orion13 Can you reproduce the problem with only the code from my answer?

Comment: I wrote it again in a new page, without some extra packages I previously had and it works perfect!!!! thank you! very much!